# c# how i can get selected rows name of gridcontrol devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

i want get rows values by clicked the row. How i can get rows name of GridControl?

```
  private void btnMusteriDuzenle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int[] celRows = ((GridView)grdMusteriListele.MainView).GetSelectedRows();


            MessageBox.Show(selRows.ToString());


        }
```

Comment: @codemthnth `DevExpress` has some of the best documentation I've seen have you even looked at / read their documentation. they give plenty examples on how to do this.

Comment: yes i searched but unlucky i could not get the document. still searching but nothing found. just wanna get selected row name. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GetSelectedRows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetSelectedRows.method) method returns **handles** of the selected rows.
To retrieve row cell values, utilize the following API: [GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetRowCellValue.overloads), [GetRowCellDisplayText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetRowCellDisplayText.overloads):

```
int[] selectedRows = gridView.GetSelectedRows();
for(int i = 0, i < selectedRows.Length, i++){
    int id = (int)gridView.GetRowCellValue(selectedRows[i], "Id");
    //...
}
```

If you are using the **single-selection** mode(the [OptionsSelection.MultiSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnViewOptionsSelection.MultiSelect.property) property is **false**) you can use the following API to obtain cell values of a focused row: [GetFocusedRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellValue.overloads), [GetFocusedRowCellDisplayText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellDisplayText.overloads). These API utilized the handle of a currently focused row via the [FocusedRowHandle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle.property) property:

```
int focusedId = (int)gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Id");
```

To learn more, take a look at [Accessing Rows in Code. Row Handles](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3484/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Views/Grid-View/Rows#row_access) help article.